# how to grep the string using special character as delimiter in oracle?

Tags: sql, oracle

I want to fetch the ip addresses which ends before the first special character from the below patterns

```
SQL> select distinct cell_name from v$cell_state;

CELL_NAME
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
10.160.0.39;10.160.0.40
10.160.0.41;10.160.0.42
10.160.0.43;10.160.0.44
10.160.0.45;10.160.0.46
10.160.0.47;10.160.0.48
10.160.0.49;10.160.0.50
10.160.0.51;10.160.0.52

expected output:
10.160.0.39
10.160.0.41
10.160.0.43
10.160.0.45
10.160.0.47
10.160.0.49
10.160.0.51

SQL> select distinct cell_name from v$cell_state;

CELL_NAME
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
10.160.0.39,10.160.0.40
10.160.0.41,10.160.0.42
10.160.0.43,10.160.0.44
10.160.0.45,10.160.0.46
10.160.0.47,10.160.0.48
10.160.0.49,10.160.0.50
10.160.0.51,10.160.0.52

expected output:
10.160.0.39
10.160.0.41
10.160.0.43
10.160.0.45
10.160.0.47
10.160.0.49
10.160.0.51

SQL> select distinct cell_name from v$cell_state;

CELL_NAME
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
190.160.14.3
190.160.14.4
190.160.14.5
190.160.14.8
190.160.14.9

expected output:
190.160.14.3
190.160.14.4
190.160.14.5
190.160.14.8
190.160.14.9
```

I want to write a  query to achieve it fetches the ip's in all above 3 scenario's Even if there is no special characters then it should fetch the existing ip output

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`[^;, ]` any charter other than `;`, `,` and 
`*`     any number of occurrences

```
select  distinct 
        regexp_substr(cell_name,'[^;, ]*')  

from    v$cell_state
;
```

Demo

```
select  regexp_substr('10.160.0.39;10.160.0.40' ,'[^;, ]*')
       ,regexp_substr('10.160.0.39,10.160.0.40' ,'[^;, ]*')
       ,regexp_substr('10.160.0.39'             ,'[^;, ]*')

from    dual
;
```

Comment: Hi Dudu,super.Could you please explain little how it is fetching even if there is no special char

Comment: if i want to add space also a special char then how to put that in special char list?